# ERC20 method to keep track of current block number

Tags: blockchain, erc-20

I'm looking for a method to include in my first smart contract which gets the current Ethereum block number. I've seen some indications that block.number will do this, but I'm not completely certain. Additionally, is there a list somewhere of all available methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `block.number` should satisfy your requirements. There's no formal function specification in the ERC20 standard to keep track of block number. How you would do it would depend on  what you want to do. For example, if you wanted to record the last block that a function of any kind was called at for the contract you could do something like

```
uint256 public lastBlock;

function setLastBlock()
     internal
     returns (bool)
{
    lastBlock = block.number;
    return true;
}
```

Then somewhere in your functions you could call use `require(setLastBlock());` which would set the `lastBlock` variable.

The following  solidity documents list all the available global variables:

- https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#cheatsheet

Some general but useful links:

- https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html
- https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html

Comment: No problem! I'd double check the post as I believe the edit I made was done after your comment which had a typo in the function code.